# Validate database backup For Innodb tables

Tags: mysql

Every fortnight, I take MySQL database dump from slave and then perform following steps as backup validation.

1. Number of Tables in every database.
2. Validate Schema of tables.
3. Validate random records for important tables.
4. An approximate(as its a backup) count of records in the table (only for MyISAM)

I am able to complete the activity. However since most of the tables are in InnoDB, I am not able to validate count properly. What solution can be there as count(*) is too slow in innodb?

Comment: Share a part of your code, please

Comment: Code not required. I am looking for strategy to validate InnoDB count.

Comment: I suppose one option is MySQL Enterprise

Comment: @Strawberry any other suggestion in terms of idea

Comment: I think this question belongs in the dba forum